# How can I vertical align h2 element in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vAbIa) here, anyone know how to vertically and horizontally align h2 to the centre of the div element?

**html**

```
<div class="container">
   <h2 class="center">
      Hello World!
   </h2>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
 .container {
position:relative !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
 display:table;
}

.center {
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
z-index: 200;
position: absolute;
  vertical-align:middle;
font-size: 4em;
margin: 0;
padding: 1em .75em 0 .75em;
line-height: .8;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #666666;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: sorry, updated the post..

Comment: .center {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 200;
    **position: inherit;**
      vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em .75em 0 .75em;
    line-height: .8;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #666666;
      display:table-cell;
    }

**SEE DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/athullive/666arumv/ **

Comment: would this be a simple solution ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpqHC (no absolute or tablelike needed)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `positoin` properties and apply `100%` for your `body` and `html`.

```
body,html{height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;} 
.container {    
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0;
 display:table;
}

.center {
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
z-index: 200;    
vertical-align:middle;
font-size: 4em;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #666666;
display:table-cell;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9payrewu/)

Comment: thanks, but in my case I do need the `position:relative !important;`

Comment: If you want you can add it. It will not affect the answer. check this http://jsfiddle.net/9payrewu/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is def a better solution.
But here is also one:

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    border: solid thin #000;
}
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}
.center {
    border: solid thin #ddd;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    bottom:25%;
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: .8;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #666666;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex;` could be an hint with little CSS to set :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEufx

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
.container {
  min-height:100%;
  display:flex;
}

.center { 
  margin:auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #666666;
}
```